# Generate Random Number based on a Condition?

Tags: php, random

Is it possible to generate a random number based on a condition?

I would like to generate a random number, *1-1000*. However, I do not want the same random value to generate any number that is already present within my variables

```
<?php
    $low= 0;
    $height= 1000;
    $num_1 =1;
    $num_2 =3;
    $num_3 =4;
    $num_4 =6;
    $num_5 =2;

    $num = rand($low, $height) & != ($num_1 - $num_5) ;
?>
```

Comment: Am not understanding the logic here

Comment: what is your expectation exactly?

Comment: Use an array to store the "blacklist" of numbers, and then check whether your new random number is in that list. It won't involve `num1 - num5`; that's **subtraction**, not how you specify a range of values in PHP.

Comment: To draw randoms within a range, while excluding some subset of that range, the common idiom is known as "draw and discard".  Draw a random, if it's in the subset, discard it and draw another.  Draw-and-discard is also useful in preventing modulo bias.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to draw unique randoms, generate the range, shuffle it randomly, then pop values off the list sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$low= 0;
$height= 1000;
$numbers = array(1, 3, 4, 6, 2);

$num = rand($low, $height);

while (in_array($num, $numbers)) {
    $num = rand($low, $height);
}
```

I am assuming that adding your 'not allowed' values to an array would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand I think you are implying that you need [UNIQUE](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unique) random numbers to  variables.

Although for your case of five numbers you can use the solution provided above, yet the solution does not gurantee smooth running (what if the rand function were to return the same number indefinitely, though practically least possible for large numbers).

ALGORITHM:

```
low = 0
height = 1000

val = array(1,2,3,4,5,....1000)// better not to waste cycles generating them

i=0

while(i<5)
{
t = rand(low , height);
num[i] = val[t];
val[t] = val[height];   
i++;
height--;
}
```

Comment: Love this algorithm - stolen for future use - noticed that array didn't start at 0 could cause error due to 0 index of array so made a quick tweak - OP if this is what you wanted this is a wonderful answer - if it isn't add it to your code bank in case you need it in future +1!

Answer (score 0):

Bear with this long conditional:

```
$num = rand($low, $height);
while($num == $num_1 || $num == $num_2 || $num == $num_3 || $num == $num_4 || $num == $num_5){
    $num = rand($low, $height);
}
```